# Is the multiplication operator documented for sets?

Tags: delphi, set

I noticed this block of code today and was wondering if these type of operations are documented somewhere and why it was done this way (Performance, etc).

```
var
  Shift: TShiftState
begin
  if [ssShift, ssCtrl] * Shift <> [] then
  begin
    ...
  end;
end;
```

It looks to me from my testing and just looking at the code like this is checking if Shift contains either `ssShift` or `ssCtrl`. Is this documented behavior or is it just leveraging the fact that the set is actually stored as an integer internally?

Comment: An internal integer representation wouldn't be sufficient to enable the given calculation all by itself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's not the multiplication operator when used with sets; it's the intersection operator. This is documented, and has been since pre-Delphi days. See [Expressions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Expressions_%28Delphi%29#Set_Operators), particularly the section on set operations. They're the standard mathematical operators for union, intersection, sub- and super-sets, equality, inequality, and membership.

Here's a summary of the table from the docs:

```
Operator  Operation     Operand Types  Result Type  Example  
--------  ---------     -------------  -----------  -------
+          union        set            set          Set1 + Set2 
-          difference   set            set          S - T 
*          intersection set            set          S * T 
<=         subset       set            Boolean      Q <= MySet 
>=         superset     set            Boolean      S1 >= S2 
=          equality     set            Boolean      S2 = MySet 
<>         inequality   set            Boolean      MySet <> S1 
in         membership   ordinal, set   Boolean      A in Set1
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I never thought to look at the expressions. I was looking at the set definitions under http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi). And I really should know this having working on the language since the old Turbo Pascal days :)

Comment: Searching in the docwiki for set operators gives you that page as first hit.